# AIR LocalConnection one to many possible?

Tags: air, localconnection

I am using the AS3 localConnection Class

to connect one AIR desktop application with another over a local network.

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to use localConnection to connect to more than 1 device, or is it strictly 1:1 ?

Comment: `LocalConnection` doesn't work over a network, local or otherwise. The [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html) clearly says: "`LocalConnection` objects can communicate only among files that are running on the same client computer."

Comment: wrong. I've already confirmed it DOES indeed work over a local network

Comment: I can only assume that 'same client computer' = 'local network', in any event the documentations seems very misleading. There is also more than 1 youtube demo I've seen with a mobile based AIR client communicating with a desktop client over a local network. More confusion since the documentation also states there is no mobile support for this feature!